# C - less than or equal to with bitwise operators

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

I'm trying to create a function to determine whether x is less than or equal to y.
The legal operators are `!` `~` `&` `^` `|` `+` `<<` `>>`, and the function says "if x <= y  then return 1, else return 0"

My thought process is to check whether `x-y` is negative, and then right shift 31 bits and compare with 1. No matter what adjustments I do, it returns 0, when it's expecting 1.

This is what I have so far:

```
int isLessOrEqual(int x, int y) {
return (((x - y) >> 31) & 1) | (!(x^y));
}
```

Can anyone please help me see what I'm doing wrong?

I also tried with all of these return statements:

```
 return (!(x^y)) | (((x+(~y+1)) >> 31 ) & 1);
 return ~(((x+(~y+1)) >> 31 ) & 1) |  (!(x^y));
 return !(((x+(~y+1)) >> 31 ) & 1) |  (!(x^y));
 return (((x+(~y+1)) >> 31 ) & 1);

 return (((x+y+(~1)) >> 31 ) & 1) |  (!(x^y));
 return (((x+y+(~1) >> 31 ) & 1) |  (!(x^y));
 return (((x+(~y+1)) >> 31 ) & 0);
```

Comment: Write a loop iterating from MSB of each operand and downwards. At the first place you encounter a difference, you've found the smallest number. Or do you have even more artificial requirements such as "must be single expression"?

Comment: Can you provide example values that return 0 when you'd expect 1 (or vice versa)?

Comment: Btw right-shifting signed, possibly negative numbers, isn't a great idea.

Comment: "and then right shift 31 " assumes a certain bit-width for `int` - so not portable for general usage.

Comment: Note that the difference of two `int`s can overflow.

Comment: Also, `-` is not among the operators you say you can use.

Comment: "*No matter what adjustments I do, it returns 0*" -- when I pass equal arguments to your function, it returns 1 for me, as I would expect.  In fact, it seems to work as desired for me for lots of inputs.

Comment: Conspicuously, you can have `+` but _not_ `-` (which would make things easy). Note that `x - y` can be defined as x plus the two's complement of y. So, `x - y` goes to `x + (~y + 1)`

Comment: @JohnBollinger: `isLessOrEqual(INT_MIN, INT_MAX)` as shown in the question returns 0 (in a typical C implementation) but should return 1.

Comment: Ok, @EricPostpischil. I said the function worked for me for lots of inputs -- in contrast to the OP's claim that it always returned 0 -- not that it would work for *all* inputs.

Comment: Since you seem (pretty reasonably) to be assuming two's complement representation, you can determine whether the sign bit of `x` is set as whether `x & INT_MIN` is non-zero.  No shifting required for that.

Comment: I updated the answer! I tried many different options, should have shown that to begin with. I cannot use loops or if statements. Only the operators specified

Comment: And it is supposed to be a 32 bit input

Comment: As I said already, the difference of two `int`s can overflow.  This is true whether you compute it with the `-` operator or by performing a two's complement conversion and using the `+` operator.  Failing to deal with this appears to be a significant flaw in all of the alternatives presented in the question.

Comment: This actually _**CAN**_ be done. Your saving grace is the `+` operator and a very useful hint by **John Bollinger** about detecting negative numbers. The answer boils down to a fairly _short_ expression. (BTW, I think this is an evil kind of homework to give to students.)

Comment: Sorry for a late response, but I realized we can't use global variables such as INT_MIN. Is there a way to write the equivalent of INT_MIN?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not going to do your assignment for you, but I will try to get you pointed in the right direction.

> My thought process is to check whether `x-y` is negative, and then right shift 31 bits and compare with 1.

I take you to mean that you want to test whether `x-y` is negative *by* shifting the result and comparing with 1, and then to use that in determining the function's return value.  That's more or less ok, but there is some room for concern about right shifting negative numbers, as the result is implementation defined.  I do not think that's causing you trouble in practice, however.

> No matter what adjustments I do, it returns 0, when it's expecting 1.

*In some cases*, yes.  But there are many other cases where that approach, correctly implemented, produces the desired result.  About 75% of cases, in fact. Specifically,

- **it works (only) when `x-y` does not overflow**.

Additionally,

- since you're not allowed to use the `-` operator, you'll need to perform the two's complement conversion and use `+` instead.
- you can avoid the shifting by ANDing with `INT_MIN` instead of with 1.  This yields a nonzero result (`INT_MIN`) when and only when the other operand of the `&` has its sign bit set.  If you like, you can convert non-zero to exactly 1 by logically negating twice (`!!x`).
- You can slightly simplify the overall computation by using `y-x` instead of `x-y`.  Then you don't need special accommodation for the `x == y` case.

You know (or can know) that neither `x - y` nor `y - x` overflows when `x` and `y` have the same sign.<sup>*</sup>  In that case, you can use one or another variation on testing the arithmetic difference of the arguments.  On the other hand, there is a simpler alternative when the two have differing signs (left as an exercise).

To combine those into a single expression, you can compute bitmasks that effect a selection between two alternatives.  Schematically:

```
return (WHEN_SIGNS_MATCH_MASK(x, y) & IS_DIFFERENCE_NON_NEGATIVE(y, x))
        | (WHEN_SIGNS_DIFFER_MASK(x, y) & ...);
```

The `WHEN_SIGNS_MATCH_MASK` should evaluate to 0 when the signs differ and to -1 (== all bits 1) or another appropriate value when the signs are the same.  The `WHEN_SIGNS_DIFFER_MASK` implements the opposite sense of that sign comparison.  The `IS_DIFFERENCE_NON_NEGATIVE` expands to your subtraction-based computation, and the `...` is the alternative approach for the differing-sign case. (I've implied using macros.  You don't need to use macros, but doing so will probably make your code clearer.)

---

<sup>*</sup>A sufficient condition, but not a necessary one.